# how to pass list in functions in C

Tags: c

I am new here and I need some help. I want to learn how can I pass a `NULL` list to a function fill it and then returning it to my main function.
**FOR INSTANCE:**

```
#include <cstdio>

typedef struct empNode {

    char amka[12];

    char first_name[30];
    char last_name[30];

    int year; //etos proslhpshs
    float salary;

    int num_of_children;
    Child *children;

    struct empNode *next;
} empNode;

void load_employees_from_file(empNode **employees);

//===========================================================
int main(void) {

    empNode *employees = NULL;

    load_employees_from_file(&employees);

    while (employees != NULL) {

        printf("%s ", employees->amka);
        employees = employees->next;
    }

}

//===========================================================
void load_employees_from_file(empNode **employees) {

    FILE * fp;
    int num_of_employees;
    int i;

    fp = fopen("employees.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("Something went wrong, try again.\n");
        return;
    }

    // here we read the first line of file to see how employee we have
    fscanf(fp, "%d ", &num_of_employees);

    while (num_of_employees) {

        *employees = (empNode*) malloc(sizeof (empNode));

        fscanf(fp, "%s ", (*employees)->amka);
        fscanf(fp, "%s ", (*employees)->first_name);
        fscanf(fp, "%s ", (*employees)->last_name);
        fscanf(fp, "%d ", &(*employees)->year);
        fscanf(fp, "%f ", &(*employees)->salary);
        fscanf(fp, "%d\n", &(*employees)->num_of_children);

        if ((*employees)->num_of_children > 0) {

            (*employees)->children = (Child*) malloc(((*employees)->num_of_children) * sizeof (Child));

            for (i = 0; i < (*employees)->num_of_children; i++) {

                fscanf(fp, "%s ", (*employees)->children[i].fname);
                strcpy((*employees)->children[i].lname, (*employees)->last_name);
                fscanf(fp, "%d\n", &(*employees)->children[i].year_of_birth);
            }
        }

        (*employees)->next = (empNode*) malloc(sizeof (empNode));
        *employees = (*employees)->next;

        num_of_employees--;
    }

    fclose(fp);
}
```

I get an error when I am running the `while` in my `main` function, more specifically my program crashes.

**-------------------------------------------------------------------**
ok let mu put it more clearly, after corrections i dont have problem with my list in the function the problem is that my list cant transfer to my main function. **A clear example of this this:**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
}node;

void read_int(node **nn);
 int main(void)
 {
    node *nn=NULL;
    read_int(&nn);
    printf("%d", nn->data);

    return 0;
 }

 void read_int(node **nn)
 {
    FILE *fp;

    fp=fopen("test.txt", "r");

    fscanf(fp, "%d", (*nn)->data);
    fclose(fp);
 }
```

here is exactly the same problem and more easier to understund, the **test.txt** files contains just the number 2. but i cant print it in my main.

Comment: C does not have a _list_ type. What do you mean with "NULL list"?

Comment: @Olaf - `empNode` is obviously a linked-list structure (the definition is included in the source code above).

Comment: You should clarify your question by including the specific error you're observing, and explaining what it is about the error that you don't understand.

Comment: i want to load some information from a file to a list(my struct empNode), and then i want to display that list, but in 2 diferrent functions.

Comment: i dont get an error, just when i am compiling my program crushes

Comment: I think you mean it crashes when you *run* the program, right? If it crashes while compiling then you need a new compiler... How do you know it's crashing, as opposed to just exiting with no output?

Comment: @DaoWen: That does not change the missleading phrasing. Such is often an indicator of some fundamental missconception. And a pointer is not a _list; but just a - pointer.

Comment: @Olaf - True—but it would probably be more helpful to use your comment to explain that a more accurate description is "a null pointer to a linked list". (If you don't think he knows the correct terms to use, what's the point in asking him to explain it again?)

Comment: @DaoWen: It is often better to make someone think about what he actually wants to accomplish instead of just feeding him a fish.

Comment: @Olaf - An anecdote for you: I had a weird teacher in elementary school. Every time I asked her if I could go to the bathroom, she would ask, "I don't know, _can_ you?" It wasn't until a couple years later that I realized she was trying to get me to say *may* instead of *can*. It would have been much more effective for her to explain to me the difference between "can" and "may" rather than repeating her sarcastic response over and over in hopes that I'd somehow figure it out on my own.

Comment: You have an error in `struct empNode`, the data member :  `salary` is redundant. Στην Ελλαδα δεν έχει λεφτά, αφού! :)

Comment: @simplicisveritatis hehe lol nice joke.

Comment: @DaoWen oh, that was a nice statement.(that with an anecdote)

Comment: @DaoWen: But you now still remember this and know you should be carefully wording in gerenal. If she had just told you, you might have gotten **that** one correct, but possibly not noticed the larger picture. I prefer to teach a man fishing (and preparing, seasoning and frying/cooking) instead of just giving him a fish.

Comment: @Olaf - No, you missed the point. Her efforts were completely worthless because *all she did was confuse me*. I learned the correct usage of may vs can some time later (someone else *actually explained it*), and some time even later I thought back on that experience with the first teacher and I realized what she had been trying (but failed) to do. Don't get me wrong—I totally agree with the "teach a man to fish" idea—but this is like asking your student "what is the best bait for trout?" when he has *no idea* and no way of knowing (that's not a useful question—just tell the answer instead).

Comment: @DaoWen: This is the difference between a kid and an adult: The latter should be able to notice he does not know something and do some research on his own. If you always expect to get the answers presented, you will never use your own neurons, but always depend on others. You have the last word.

Answer (score 2):

Skimming through your code, there seems to be several problems. You should learn to use a debugger, which would let you step through the code line-by-line during execution and observe the actual behavior.

Here are some obvious issues I think you should look at:

1. What do you think the value of `*employees` will be when the `while` loop exits? Specifically, think about this statement: `*employees = (*employees)->next;`
2. I assume you want this list to be NULL-terminated (otherwise, the `while (employees != NULL)` in your main function wouldn't make sense). In that case, where do you set the `NULL` terminator value? You don't seem to ever set the `next` field to `NULL` anywhere...
3. Why do you call `malloc` twice in the body of your loop? You seem to be allocating two different blocks of memory to represent the same employee.

I think #1 above is the reason that your program is crashing right now. (But if you fix that issue, your program will probably still crash due to one of the other issues.)

Right now, on the last iteration of your loop, you do this:

```
    (*employees)->next = (empNode*) malloc(sizeof (empNode));
    *employees = (*employees)->next;
```

This means that `*employees` (which points to `employees` from `main`) will always end up pointing to an uninitialized `empNode` struct. Since the memory is uninitialized, the `next` pointer will be garbage. That's definitely going to cause some problems.

Answer (score 2):

In your function `void load_employees_from_file(empNode **employees)`

Change :

```
(*employees)->next = (empNode*) malloc(sizeof (empNode));
```

to

```
(*employees)->next = NULL;
```

as immediately after that `*employees` becomes `next` and the `while` loop starts from the beginning where memory is dynamically allocated:

```
*employees = (empNode*) malloc(sizeof (empNode));
```

and then populated.

Otherwise, if this was the last employee, the `next` element remains the `NULL` pointer.

In this way, your `main`'s `while` loop termination condition will be `true` when the last `next` element (pointing to `NULL`) is reached.

Comment: This doesn't work. Changing `*employees` on the next iteration doesn't update the value of `(*employees)->next` from the previous iteration.

Comment: OK, give me a sec... :)

Comment: @DaoWen Then, `(*employees)->next = NULL;` should be transferred in the beginning of the `while` loop, right ?

Comment: Or maybe after the loop? There are many ways you could write this code to function correctly. I don't think there's one correct answer.

Comment: that stoped my crash but still doenst run my while, which means that employees is null(i supose), the thing that i want to do is, load employes from a file and then print them, but in 2 different function and i cant pass my list(maybe cause i dont know if i am passing it correctly)

Comment: @DaoWen absolutely, you are right. Btw, your questions are great (you should be a teacher/ lecturer, if you are not) :)

Comment: @LipoStyle write few lines to check your code at the different stages that you think are suspicious. Observe the values printed and check if they are valid (or as expected)

Comment: @LipoStyle - There's still a big issue in the code. `*employee` should be set to point to the *head* of the list (in essence returning a pointer to the whole list to the calling function). As it's written right now, `*employee` is reset every time a new node is added, so you end up with the *last* element being stored instead. (That should explain why the loop in `main` isn't giving the expected results.)